# Better solution to supress 'mouseleave' temporarily

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

Basically I unbind the `mouseleave` after an element is clicked. But I want to have the `mouseleave`-event for this element working again **when** another element is clicked. My code is working, but it feels bulky, because I repeat the animation on and on in my code.

Is there no other method to supress the `mouseleave` temporarily other than unbinding and "re-binding" ? Any suggestions ?

[Here's my example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLR9U/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 CONTAINER ONE
</div>

<div class="container">
 CONTAINER TWO
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //the default hover-event
    $('.container').hover(
        function(){
              $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':'10px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        },
        function() {
              $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':'0px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
        }
    );



    $('.container').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // enables the mouseleave for all other `.container`s again.
        // also bring the old clicked element into unhovered position again
        $('.container')
                .bind('mouseleave',function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':'0px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
                }).not(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':'0px'},{queue:false,duration:160});

        // supress the mouseleave for the clicked element
            $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a better way ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/LcsnY/1/)):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var over = function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':'10px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
    };
    var out = function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({'padding-bottom':'0px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
    };
    //the default hover-event
    $('.container').hover(over, out);



    $('.container').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // enables the mouseleave for all other `.container`s again.
        // also bring the old clicked element into unhovered position again
        $('.container').bind('mouseleave', out).not(this).each(out);

        // supress the mouseleave for the clicked element
        $(this).unbind('mouseleave');
    })
});
```

Comment: +1 definitely more readable and probably a bit faster too! Thanks for that, should have thought of something like this in the first place. Let's see if there's an even niftier solution...